# How do I use "attr()" in jQuery in the way I want to?

Tags: jquery, html, css, attributes, attr

Here is my code:

```
let timer = {};
$('#menu_top li').hover(function () {
    let tag = $(this);
    let timerAttr = tag.attr('data-timer');
    let menudowniconrotate = $('#menu_top span').attr('id') ;
    alert(menudowniconrotate) ;

    clearTimeout(timer[timerAttr]);
    timer[timerAttr] =setTimeout(function () {
        $('#'+ menudowniconrotate).css({
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
            "transform": "rotate(180deg)"});
        $(' > ul', tag).fadeIn(200);
        tag.addClass('activemenu') ;
        $(' > .submenu3', tag).fadeIn(200) ;
    }, 300)
```

I want to get attributes info about each `span` tags in my code separately. When I hover my mouse on `li` tag, that contains that `span` tag , it works perfectly. When I'm trying to get attributes from `li` tags but it just gets the first `span` in the first `li` tag attribute with `attr()` function whether I hover the mouse on any `li` tag available ....

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, you need `$(this).find('span')` instead of `$('#menu_top span')`

Comment: Add a stack snippet or jsfiddle that reproduces your problem. I can't make any sense out of what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @Morpheus Thank you for your answer , it worked perfectly but I don't know how to upvote you , give a like , credit or choosing your answer as the best answer since I'm not able too see any options out there , I'm new here . anyway , thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi 2pamine - @Morpheus needs to add their comment as an answer so that you can upvote and accept it.   We quite often add quick comments like this instead of full answers as we don't have time to flesh out a full answer and people downvote if the answer is incomplete.  There may also be a duplicate (very similar question) which would also bring downvotes to any answers (again without time to research).   This way both of you can get on with other work until Morpheus has time to enter a fully detailed answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m oh I see ,  thanks for your care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector `$('#menu_top span')` is selecting all `span` elements under the `#menu_top` parent. When you try to select `id` attribute of the returned array, the value returned will always be the `id` from the first element in array.

To fix the problem you are having, use `$(this).find('span')` to select the `span` element of the currently hovered `li`.